# Why is SQL Server's query optimizer joining a table against itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm writing a report that needs to pull data from a view that I'm not authorized to modify. The view is missing a column that I need for a report, so I attempted to join it against one of its source tables. However, this is causing it to take twice as long to execute.

A look at the execution plan shows that it performs two scans of the table and merge joins them together. Is there a hint I can use to convince the query optimizer to visit the table only once?

Abstracted fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a44d/1/0

Comment: Just look at the output columns for both scan operators. Once it's for the description column, then it's scanned for the columns in the view. Are you forced to use this view? I would either create a new view (indexed, since it's possible) or I would just use the base tables without the view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Are you sure? Everything I recall reading states that views and iTVF's are expanded into their surrounding query, which is then optimized as a unit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If they're optimized separately, why can the execution plan be altered by adding a where clause to the surrounding query? In this case, adding "WHERE Id = 12345" causes it to use a seek rather than a scan. Views can even use different indexes to access a table if some of the index columns are not used or if the outer query specifies the earlier columns in the index.

Comment: I had this issue as well with ORM-generated queries. I believe it is not possible to make the optimizer fold redundant accesses. Not even in trivial cases.

Comment: @marceln Unfortunately, I'm required to use the view because it is guaranteed to be updated if the business logic for the filtering ever changes.

Comment: @erefewinter . . . My original comment was only accurate in a particular context (I was thinking of cached execution plans for views).  In any case, the optimizer is not smart enough to remove a join that is placed there explicitly, at least in this case.

Comment: I don't think the optimizer is going to decompose a view, and then completely re-write your query when it realizes you are hitting the same table as the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the optimizer will never eliminate a table access specified in the query unless nothing is actually referenced from that table.

There is no way to access a table less times than it is referenced in the query (as far as I know from 13 years experience). There may be a few other cases, but the only case I know of where the query optimizer can do less accesses than the number of object references is when it can optimize away a left outer or right outer join when nothing is accessed from the outer table and it is known from constraints that excluding the work will not change the number of rows or which rows would be returned in the result.